# to compare names in two cells by comparing first name,lastname or middlename is matched or not.upto 70 % match using vba code

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

in B&c columns, we will first and last name, we need to match it with full name in E column if any match is found the need to popup message box as match found. I need it to be done using vba. As I am new to coding part I not aware much about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will answer your specific question with the specific data you provided:

```
Sub CompareNames()

Dim FirstName, FullName, cell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim NameArray(4) As Variant

Set FirstName = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B5")
Set FullName = ActiveSheet.Range("E1")

i = 0

For Each cell In FirstName
    If Len(cell) > 0 Then
        If InStr(cell, " ") > 0 And InStr(cell.Offset(0, 1), " ") > 0 Then
            NameArray(i) = UCase(Left(cell.Value, InStr(cell.Value, " ") - 1) & " " & Right(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, Len(cell.Offset(0, 1)) - InStr(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, " ")))
            i = i + 1
        ElseIf InStr(cell, " ") > 0 Then
            NameArray(i) = UCase(Left(cell.Value, InStr(cell.Value, " ") - 1) & " " & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
            i = i + 1
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Offset(0, 1), " ") > 0 Then
            NameArray(i) = UCase(cell.Value & " " & Right(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, Len(cell.Offset(0, 1)) - InStr(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, " ")))
            i = i + 1
        Else
            NameArray(i) = UCase(cell.Value & " " & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
Next

If UBound(Filter(NameArray, FullName)) > -1 = True Then
    MsgBox ("Match Found")
Else
    MsgBox ("No Match Found")
End If
```

However, it sounds like you could more easily accomplish your task with a standard Excel function, albeit without the message box. For instance, you could enter the following in the cell adjacent to the full name:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$5,LEFT(E1,SEARCH(" ",E1)-1),$C$1:$C$5,RIGHT(E1,LEN(E1)-SEARCH(" ",E1)))
```

Both of these assume that the list of first names is in B1:B5, last names are in C1:C5, and the full name you're testing is in E1. Also, notably, names must match exactly (i.e.: "Lucy Morrone" is not the same as "Lucy M Morrone", so no match will be detected.)

Comment: Is there a way to divide names in B & C columns.ex: in B1 cell LUCY and M , then combine divided names in  B and C columns ex:LOUIS and MORRONE as LOUIS MORRONE and then compare with E1 value.Then we can find match.How to code it for whole range of B & C columns and then compare with E1 value.

Comment: Can anyone help me how to do it.

Comment: You could use this formula in the column after the last name to create a column of full names:
`=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IFERROR(LEFT(B1,SEARCH(" ",B1)-1),B1),C1)`
Then this in F1 to search for your entry in E1:
`=COUNTIF($D$1:$D$5,E3)`

Comment: Thanks rmbradburn.If possible can you implement the formula in code and provide full code for the process.I am new to vba and not aware much on coding part.

Comment: I've edited the VBA in my answer above to add this functionality.

Comment: for some names in c column ex: we will get like lucy in b column and M MORRONE in c column in that case how to divide name in c column and then combine both b and c columns name and then compare with e column name.if  approach like these  how to solve  it.

Comment: I've edited the code above to accommodate the potential of an extra initial in Column C.

Comment: When i run the above code its showing no match found.when the names are exact matched .I am facing difficulty to understand the above logic.